# SLF4J and logger factories

Tags: java, reflection, logging, slf4j

I thought SLF4J would load **org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder** via reflection but looking at the code in **org.slf4j.LoggerFactory**, it is not the case:

```
StaticLoggerBinder.getSingleton().getLoggerFactory();
```

That might suggest that when they packaged the slf4j-api.jar, they had either **slf4j-simple.jar** (or **slf4j-nop.jar**) in the classpath, however that would result in a circular dependency as **ILoggerFactory** interface that the above method returns is defined in **slf4j-api.jar**.

So, I think when they packaged **slf4j-api.jar**, they had a stub implementation of **StaicLoggerBinder** (and other similar classes) which they would compile but then remove the .class files from the jar. Sounds a bit unkosher, doesn't it?

What kind of build tool would one use to achieve such a result? Specifically, if I am using Maven, how do I build such jars where classes produced during compile time are excluded from the artifact? There could be anonymous and other inner/nested classes being produced too, should they be removed too?

Comment: The question was what would the build step be for something like Maven? The fact that a whole package is deleted after compilation makes sense but I am trying to employ a similar static binding strategy and was trying to configure how to delete classes/traits generated by a scala file. I am now deleting all MyMainStub*.class after compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [pom.xml](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.4/slf4j-api-1.6.4.pom) and at the sources of [slf4j-api](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.4/slf4j-api-1.6.4-sources.jar).

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
        <goals>
         <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <tasks>
        <echo>Removing slf4j-api's dummy StaticLoggerBinder and StaticMarkerBinder</echo>
        <delete dir="target/classes/org/slf4j/impl"/>
      </tasks>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

> So, I think when they packaged slf4j-api.jar, they had a stub implementation of StaicLoggerBinder (and other similar classes) which they would compile but then remove the .class files from the jar.

That's right and it's necessary to implement [static binding](http://v4forums.wordpress.com/2008/12/27/slf4j-vs-jcl-dynamic-binding-vs-static-binding/).

Answer (score 2):

> "So, I think when they packaged slf4j-api.jar, they had a stub implementation of StaicLoggerBinder (and other similar classes) which they would compile but then remove the .class files from the jar. Sounds a bit unkosher, doesn't it?"

That's how it's done yes. I wouldn't say that's unkosher - it's a necessary "evil" to be able to support multiple implementations in a rather simple way.
[SLF4J StaticLoggerBinder](http://slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.html)

Comment: Also related:
http://articles.qos.ch/thinkAgain.html